# Setting a nginx header using subrequest with Lua

Tags: nginx, lua

I've got the following location setup in my site-routing.conf

```
location = "/test" {
  proxy_pass http://localhost$is_args$args;
  access_by_lua_file ./header.lua; 
}
```

Inside of my header.lua file I'm making a subrequest to get some data from another service. The return value from this service is a token that I want to add to the header of the proxy_pass request.

The code in header.lua looks like this:

```
  local cjson = require "cjson"

  res = ngx.location.capture(
    '/get_token',
    { method = ngx.HTTP_GET, args = { id: 1234 } }
  );

  if res.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
    body = cjson.decode(res.body)
    local token = body["token"]
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, token)
    ngx.headers["Token"] = token
  else
    ngx.say("Failed to retrieve token")
    ngx.exit(401);
  end
```

It throws an exception when I try to set the `ngx.headers` or `ngx.req.set_headers()` method. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: provide more info. what exception? any reason why you have the keys "Token" and "token"? Is that a typo or is that as it should be?

Comment: There is no api `ngx.headers` and `ngx.req.set_headers()` in lua-nginx-module, maybe you want [ngx.header](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxheaderheader) and [ngx.req.set_header](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqset_header)?

Comment: @xiaochen - Ah, I might have called the wrong method. I did find a solution that worked for me after digging into a few other stackoverflow posts. I created a variable within my nginx.conf and then did `proxy_set_header TOKEN $token` where $token would be the value from the body of the subrequest. Did the setting using `ngx.var.token = "some value"`

Comment: Do you found how to set headers from lua?